# How do I add a UICollectionView inside a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewCell which I created using a visual XIB file.

The collection view is horizontally displayed.

I'm wanting to add another UICollectionView to this cell in the footer of the cell.

The cell itself is a "card" representing some information;

This diagram helps illustrate what I'm after;

[image: Card diagram]

The idea is that I can show/hide the dice imagery as many as needed, including zero; in a horizontal fashion as a child partial inside the current UICollectionCell.

Attempts using Storyboards;

- The collection cell XIB won't let me add another UICollectionView to it
- If I make a standalone UICollectionView inside the same storyboard, it won't let me add a UICollectionCell to it

The only solution I've got so far is to manually create 5 imageviews, then attach them to a collection outlet; and then I would need to do a for-loop to show/hide each die imagery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need tableview for that just in your collectionview cell xib drag another collection and set its scrolling property to vertical,then create xib from inner collectionview.

In outer collectionview cell use that method to set delegate and datasource

```
// code
override func awakeFromNib() {
   super.awakeFromNib()
   serInnerCollectionView()
}

 func serInnerCollectionView() {

 collectionViewInner.delegate = self
   collectionViewInner.dataSource = self
   collectionViewInner.register(UINib(nibName: "  FooterCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "FooterCollectionViewCellIdentifier")

}
```

Comment: Are you saying to add the collection view to the current collection view cell?

Comment: I just tried this, I'm surprised it worked; but I'm not sure its really the best way to do this.   I created my parent collection view cell, let's call this Outer.  Inside this Outer's XIB file I added another UICollectionView and tied up the outlets.   Next; I added the code you suggested with some changes.  Then created another collectionviewcell and XIB, lets call this Inner.    I coloured the Inner with Red color.  It worked in simulator.

Comment: I will accept the answer as I got it to work, but I'll look around to see if there is a different or more efficent way of doing it. Thanks

Comment: I really struggle to create a Collectionview inside a collectionVew Cell in Objective-C. Can you help me.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create normal View Controller with Collection View in the interface builder
2. Create CollectionViewCell in separate XIB. Inside this cell insert another CollectionView
3. In first VC register that collectionViewCell as sectionHeader:

   ```
   tableView.register(UINib(nibName: DashboardPagerHeader.cellIdentifier, bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: DashboardPagerHeader.cellIdentifier)
   ```
4. Create another CollectionViewCell in separate xib like before
5. Inside class of first collection view cell in awakeFromNib register cell created in step 4 like that:

   ```
   override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      collectionView.delegate = self
      collectionView.dataSource = self
      collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "  DashboardHeaderCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: DashboardHeaderCollectionViewCell.cellIdentifier)
   }
   ```

Comment: I couldn't get the `forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier` for a UICollectionView; but I did see a `forSupplementaryViewOfKind`

Comment: I found the steps to be a bit confusing.  I already have done steps (1) (2) but I can't register a header using a collection view.      I created new collection view and xib (following steps 4 and 5) but I don't understand where step 5 goes.  Does it go in the parent one, child one?